# Customize appearance QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget, qtabbar

I am currently working on Qt application. There I am using QTabWidget with several tabs.

QTabWidget is embedded into QVBoxLayout. My question is that tabs added appear centered and I would like them to be left aligned. How could I achieve that?

[image]

I would like to change appearance as well. Is the only way to override the paintEvent of QTabBar?

I am using Qt and C++, no QML

Thanks and regards

Comment: you can use stylesheet to move the tab as left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try styling the tab widget with a style sheet, this way:

```
QString ss = "QTabWidget::tab-bar { alignment: left; }";
ui->tabWidget->setStyleSheet(ss);
```

The style sheet can be set using the designer, though. Just right click the widget and choose *Change stylesheet ...* from the pop up menu, then insert the style in the dialog and click the *Ok* button when done, or the *Apply* button to check the effect before closing the dialog box.

You can find the official documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) and [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html).

You can refer to [this post](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2007/06/22/styling-the-tab-widget/) to see how to style the tab widget further.